# Trying to send and receive data to and from Intel Bluemix Cloudant database service to Android applications

Tags: android, database-connection, cloud, ibm-cloud, cloudant

Do I need to always replicate the database in order to read or write into it?
If not, how can I directly send and receive data to the Bluemix Cloudant database?

Comment: Can you share the code you've done so far? I don't understand why are saying you have to replicate the database.

Comment: It would be useful to know what tutorials/documentation you have read so far.  Cloudant has an API that allows you to read and write documents to a database - you don't have to use replication.  The API docs for managing documents are here: https://docs.cloudant.com/document.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to replicate to read and write to the database, you can use the HTTP interface directly to perform CRUD actions on the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not research properly. [Here](https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android) is a example on GitHub. Actually I am also confused and not getting how to store data in **Cloudant Database** from this example. I hope someone can. May this example help you.@user5424785